# Reconfigure android application without overwritten

Tags: android, iot

I 'm starting to build an Android app that can self-restructuring. It means this app can change its behavior after an "update". But it's not similar to common update because I don't want to publish to market and some reasons below. The idea is the app check version through server, if it's old, then download a file to proceed update.

- This is not an overwritten installation, only some parts of the app is changed, not all.
- The app have to keep working during updating.
- The download and update process must be silent, there must be no notification, pop-up or asking permission (option)

Please tell me if it 's possible and give me advice, approach, keywords, ideas or somethings helpful. Do I have to intervene system, OS or anything?. I tend to make the phone as a sensor device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way of achieving this.

You need to download whole new apk. You can't just download few part of it.

but what you can do is download app in background without user interaction.

Now to install this user has to allow installation as per security standards.

PS: If you just want to perform different action. You can download stuff n place in external/internal storage and through api call changes perform desire actions.

There are apps that doesn't use play store for updation eg. Dream11, famous cricket app.

fantasycricket.dream11.com/android-desktop.html?utm_Source